# Fedora and Samba on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, fedora, windows, virtualbox, samba

I have Linux Fedora 18 installed as a VM Guest.

Trying to share directories from the Linux VM Guest box to the Windows 7 Host. (**NOTE:** VirtualBox is installed on Windows 7, and the Linux virtual machine is created on it).

I made my Samba share using text on this link:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/fedora-19-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend

I made all proper changes in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, added proper user, etc. I even disabled SeLinux, and flushed the Iptables configuration. Samba is up and running of course. Also, I can ping Linux from Windows.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error code 0x800704cf  The network location cannot be reached. For
>   information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help

There are lots of other resources, like:

- http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/113729-password-protected-network-share.html#post978798

I did what is described there, and still having same problem. In all of the cases, I have same error.

Can you give me some tips on what I'm doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've setup Samba in the past, I've needed to create a network bridge device on the VM host, and then added the IP address for the VM guest to this bridge device.

To that end you can take a look at this tutorial which shows how to make use of a bridge device using VirtualBox, titled: [Network & sharing in VirtualBox - Full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html).